# How to reduce resolution but maintain quality?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, cs6, resolution, image-quality

I have 3 high resolution images, 1920x1080 each. Is there a way I can combine them side by side and reduce the resolution to 1280x720 but also maintain it's quality?
This is one of the images:
[image]
The other two are are similar.

P.S. The extra gray portion can be edited out.

Comment: 1920x1080 is not high resolution. 1280x720 has a aspect ratio of 16:9 as does 1920x1080 but 3 1920x1080 side by side has a ratio of 16:3 that means your image would only occupy one 1/3 of the monitor in the middle. How do you propose to fill that area?

Comment: @joojaa Nevermind, mate, solved it ... Thanks for the notice, though

Comment: You cannot reduce the size of a pixel image and "maintain its quality". (In general. It is possible with an image of a Mondriaan painting, until one of the black lines reach a width of 1 pixel – and then you cannot reduce it anymore without loosing that line.)

Answer (score -2):

Hi if you want use it in the web save it for web ctr+shift+s  but if you want for print leave hem same resolution